# How to export data from SQL Server 2008.2010 in DML (SQL script)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a tool or special query to do that. I'm not an database administrator.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Here are the steps to generate the scripts from a database along with data. The screenshots were taken using `SQL Server 2012 Management Studio` but I believe that the steps are similar for *SQL Server 2008* as well.

- Connect to the instance in which you would like to scrip the database along with data.
- Right-click on the database and select the option `Tasks --> Generate Scripts...`

[image: tasks generate scripts]

- On the *Generate and Publish Scripts* wizard, click `Next` button.

[image: introduction]

- On the *Choose objects* step, I have left the default selection `Script entire database and all database objects` checked. You can also select the option `Select specific database objects` and pick the objects of your choice.

[image: Choose objects]

- On the *Set Scripting Options* step, select the path where you would like to save the script. Click on the `Advanced` button.

[image: set scripting options]

- On the *Advanced Scripting Options* dialog, scroll down to the option `Types of data to script`. By default, this is set to `Schema only`, which means it will generate only the create object statements. If you want both object creation script along with data, select the option **`Schema and data`**. Click *OK* on the *Advanced Scripting Options* dialog and click *Next* on the *Set Scripting Options* step

[image: advanced scripting options]

- On the *Summary* step, it will show all the options that you had selected. Click *Next*.

[image: summary]

- On the *Save or Publich Scripts* step, if everything goes well you will see Success status appear against each object and the script should be saved to the location that you specified on the *Set Scripting Options* step.

[image: save or publish scripts]

Scripting the entire *AdventureWorks* database turned to be a huge `522 MB` script file!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can I select the data for which script to be generated ? Is there any such option

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean generating data script? If it is so then simply right click on the database name -Generate Scripts. In the advanced option in the wizard you get to choose "Type Of data script to add". Select data only there and you can get the data script

Answer (score 1):

to what format? 
are you only referring to 1 table or the whole database?

if you are exporting to an excel file from 1 table then all you have to do is
run a sql query statement to display all records then highlight all rows thru clicking on the top most right space of the grid and right click copy with column headers.

open excel and paste.

should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [SSMS tool pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/Download)? It is one of the best addins for SSMS.