# Generate a script of inserts from existing data with a select clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I know that in SQL Server you can right click on a database, go to tasks, generate scripts, pick a table etc. and generate a script that inserts the data into the table as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531484/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2008-2010-in-dml-sql-script)

Is there any way I can restrict the data that is being scripted out by specifying some select clauses? For example, I might want to script out only the top 100 rows in a table or all records from the Employees table that has an IsManager flag set.

If I can't do it using tasks -> generate scripts functionality, is there any other alternative way or tool?

Comment: I can't find a tasks option when right clicking on a table so I can't try this myself but you might try creating a view and see if there is a tasks -> generate scripts on it.

Comment: Sorry, it is not on a table, it is on the database itself. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: I've been able to generate scripts like that using excel, or dynamic sql queries.  I'm still not seeing how to do it under generate scripts though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this can be done directly in SSMS, but you could create a query to return the content of the sql file (at least the insert statements):

```
SELECT 'insert into yourtable (id,othercol) values (' + cast(id as varchar) + ',''' + othercol + ''');'
FROM yourtable
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea34e/1)

Be sure to cast your non-varchar fields to varchar.

Comment: An interesting way of doing it. Requires me to do a bit too much typing than I would have liked, but I suppose it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to create another table with the same schema ("script table as" -> "Create to") and from the original table do a Insert Into with a Select + Where statement.

Then you can do a "generate scripts" on the new table (and replace the tablenames in the output in a text editor).