# Restoring database to an instance with a lower version

Tags: sql-server

The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600.
That version is incompatible with server, which is running version 10.00.1600.
so, is there any solution or plugin's for restore the database ?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate. Read the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183139/sql-server-database-backup-restore-on-lower-version

Answer (score 1):

You can download SQL Express 2008 R2 (free edition) or 2012 to restore the database. The problem is not the management studio but the SQL Server engine itself. Here are the versions:

http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/

As you can see, 10.50 is the 2008 R2 and 10.00 is the 2008.

Answer (score 0):

-Frst, you export the  database on the server running version 10.50.1600 by following this link.
[Export to SQL Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531484/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2008-2010-in-dml-sql-script)

- After that, you can, import again into your current database which is running version 10.00.1600

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an this might be a rather sloppy way is to use `Database Publishing Wizard` or
you can click right on the Database in `SQL Server Management Studio` -> `Tasks` -> [`Generate Scripts`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/18/sql-server-generate-script-for-schema-and-data-sql-in-sixty-seconds-021-video/).

Select all the objects. Then when it shows the path of the script file click on the `Advanced` button. Ensure to include

`Types of data to script = Schema and Data`

`Script USE DATABASE = True`

You can check if their might be anything else required. Once the script execute try and restore it on the previous SQL Server version. If any problems arise, I would think you might have some control by fixing the scripts to inserts. It might take long but I would think it's probably the best shot.

**[INSTRUCTIONS ON GENERATING SCRIPTS](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/07/sql-server-2008-2008-r2-create-script-to-copy-database-schema-and-all-the-objects-data-schema-stored-procedure-functions-triggers-tables-views-constraints-and-all-other-database-objects/)**

Answer (score 0):

Nopes, not possible. Only thing you can do is to upgrade your instance or a newer version or generate scripts in some way and then execute these on the previous version.

**Generate scripts** – use this only if this is a small database because scripts are not necessarily in correct execution order.

**Third party tools** – there are tools that can generate scripts in correct execution order from the live database or read the backup and generate scripts from there.

More details here  [SQL Server database backup restore on lower version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183139/sql-server-database-backup-restore-on-lower-version)